# Force not escape query builder CI 3.1.8

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, query-builder

I wrote a query with codeigniter, and need to unescape subquery in `from()` method. I have a complex query, here I simplify for you

```
$this->db->from("(SELECT * FROM acme WHERE CONCAT(',', RTRIM(rule), ',') LIKE '%,PER_UNIT,%') AS acme_filtered")
become:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM acme WHERE CONCAT(',', RTRIM(rule), ',') LIKE '%,`PER_UNIT`,%') AS acme_filtered
```

the part LIKE `'%,PER_UNIT,%'` turns into 

`LIKE '%,`PER_UNIT`,%'`

data cannot be found because additional character (`) wraps the string. How to remove this character so the query turn right?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but I don't know the implications of it, as it defeats the escaping system.
Use it with care!

```
$this->db->from("(SELECT * FROM acme WHERE CONCAT(',', RTRIM(rule), ',') LIKE '%,PER_UNIT,%') AS acme_filtered");
// the rest of your "complex query" code here
$query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
$query = str_replace('%, `', '%,', $query);
$query = str_replace('`, %', ',%', $query);

$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: It could be tried, but I need final result query builder object, because it's used by another function again as base query.

Comment: It can be used like that. Just pass `$query` as an argument, you don't really need the object. Then use the `$query` variable in another active record.

Comment: It can't, because I need add `->where` or `->join` from acme_filtered in another function, plain query never know where is the key or column I need to join to..